# how to sum values in column B after looking for test1-test4 in column A

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if anyone would like to share with me how do you do a sum of column B after looking for a particular name in column A? Say for example, I want to sum test1 to test4. Then the total will be place into the "B1" where the 'In' is beside it by the way, "In" does not necessary be at "B1". I have added in a picture to ease the confusion.

[image]

I have tried doing some coding:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim lcell As Range, lrow As Long, rowToSum As Long
  lrow = 1    
Do 
  set lcell = Sheets("Sheet1").cells(lrow,1)
  If lcell = "Test1" or "Test2" Or "Test3" Or "Test4" Then
  'I'm not sure how to i sum different columns, my guess was to do a rowToSum = lcell
lrow = lrow + 1
Exit Do
End If
Loop
End Sub
```

I would appreciate it if you can clear my problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > > > Hi, I think you misunderstood my question. I want to add the values of test1 - test4 together, which means, I want to add the values at Col B, i should have 10 at B1. The code you have provided actually sum up test1-test4 in Col A, not the value on column B. – user1204868

That makes it 2 of us LOL.

Try this

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10={"Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4"})*(B1:B10))
```

**FOLLOW UP**

Put this formula in C1

If you want to use this in B1 then change it to

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10={"Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4"})*(B2:B10))
```

**VBA Code**

```
Sub Sample()
    Sheets(1).[b1] = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10={""Test1"",""Test2"",""Test3"",""Test4""})*(B2:B10))")
End Sub
```

Comment: You are getting the error because you tried entering the formula in B1 I guess :) I have updated the post above.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way would be a formula in B1
`=SUM(COUNTIF(A:A, {"Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4"}))`

which can be done in VBA via

```
Sub Test()
Sheets(1).[b1] = Evaluate("SUM(COUNTIF(A:A, {""Test1"",""Test2"",""Test3"",""Test4""}))")
End Sub
```

**Updated for clarified intent**

```
Sub Test()
Sheets(1).[b1].Value = Evaluate("SUM(SUMIF(A2:A10, {""Test1"",""Test2"",""Test3"",""Test4""},B2:B10))")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I think you misunderstood my question. I want to add the values of test1 - test4 together, which means, I want to add the values at Col B, i should have 10 at B1. The code you have provided actually sum up test1-test4 in Col A, not the value on column B.

Comment: @user1204868 well you did accept this orginally - you can simply convert my COUNTIF to a SUMIF to sum rather than count. I will update later.